# jQuery UI widget returns jQuery wrapped object instead of value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a jQuery UI custom widget:

```
$.widget('ui.objectpicker', {
    _init: function() {
        this.memberList = [/* ... */];
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    getMemberList: function() {
        // this correctly logs the value I wish to return
        console.log(this.memberList);
        return this.memberList;
    }
}
```

But when I use the above code, it returns the jQuery wrapped object instead of the member list ([JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/cT4zV/)):

```
$('#my-item').objectpicker('getMemberList');
// logs 'this.memberList', but returns the $('#my-item') object
```

How do I return `this.memberList` instead of `$('#my-item')`?

Comment: You need to look into the $.fn.widget implementation. It seems it add a wrapper to user defined method. So your return value will just be ignored. I think you will need to change the prototype of $.fn.widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my problem is my antiquated version of jQuery/jQuery-UI.  I'm running jQuery UI 1.7, and the widget factory that provides this functionality didn't land until 1.8 (thnx to <ajpiano> on the #jquery IRC channel for this tip).

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/cT4zV/).